# Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': https://www.youtube.com !== http://localhost:9000

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

This is the error message that I get:

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided
('https://www.youtube.com') does not match the recipient window's origin 
('http://localhost:9000').
```

I've seen other similar problems where the target origin is `http://www.youtube.com` and the recipient origin is `https://www.youtube.com`, but none like mine where the target is `https://www.youtube.com` and the origin is `http://localhost:9000`.

1. I don't get the problem. What is the problem?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided does not match the recipient window's origin ('null')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22194409/failed-to-execute-postmessage-on-domwindow-the-target-origin-provided-does)

Comment: I had the same issue, and the fix below by @ChrisFranklin fixed it for me; but what's weird is that with my issue, I would only get the error about half the time, and even then the video would still load (though other things would break).

Comment: @dgo same issue, it was random on page load. Turns out (I think) its due to the actual iframe contents not being fully ready by the time something else is attempting to do a postMessage. So its a race condition. And if the postMessage happens at a later time (user action), it works fine without error.

Comment: **even Google has that error itself** - open console and play the video here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: This is happening on my shopify store.  I used to dabble in web design back in the day but that was before all this crazy stuff going on now lol (before smart phones even).  Anyone know why this would happen to a shopify store? I'm just using one of their updated themes so I would think it wouldn't have any errors. The only embeds I have are social media and they all use https so idk why it's having this problem.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

I believe this is an issue with the target origin being `https`. I suspect it is because your iFrame url is using `http` instead of `https`. Try changing the url of the file you are trying to embed to be `https`.

For instance:

```js
'//www.youtube.com/embed/' + id + '?showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1&origin=http://localhost:9000';
```

to be:

```js
'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + id + '?showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1&origin=http://localhost:9000';
```

Comment: That seems to have worked. Thanks! So the problem is `http` vs. `https`? It doesn't matter that the domains differ (youtube vs. localhost)? And what exactly is target origin vs. recipient origin? How did doing what you said change the recipient origin (my url is still localhost:9000)?

Comment: The error is a little misleading. It actually has nothing to do with you being on `localhost:9000`. The problem was actually in the way you were using the youtube-api. When you declare the api as `tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";` in your code, you are telling youtube you want to use ssl. So, the change I suggested changed you to using ssl to request the videos. The error was just saying you were mixing ssl and non-ssl calls.

Comment: I came across this issue when I tried to move the iframe around in the dom.

    `playerEl = document.querySelector('iframe#ytplayer');  anotherEl.appendChild(playerEl); // yt complains on subsequent api calls`

Comment: Hi @ChrisFranklin I am getting the same error on all channel Ids except for one provided in this app ( https://creatorup.com/build-mobile-app-for-your-youtube-channel-with-ionic2-and-angular2/ ), what could be the reason for this? Thanks for any kind of help... (Y)

Comment: what if I'm using javascript to load YouTube player?

Comment: changed to https:// for youtube and my domain is https:// still not solve my problem.

Failed to execute ‘postMessage’ on ‘DOMWindow’: The target origin provided (‘https://www.youtube.com’) does not match the recipient window’s origin (‘https://test.dev’).

Comment: @andy-mccullough . have you found a solutuion ? I am stuck with same issue, I have http everywhere.

Comment: and @deelux too ?

Comment: @ishandutta2007 I found that there are 2 things maybe cause of this error message. 1 is `<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//www.youtube.com' />`. 2 is jQuery was loaded in the `<head>` section while YouTube API and js that works on YouTube API loaded in the bottom of `<body>` section. If I move jQuery to the bottom of `<body>` and remove `dns-prefetch` it has no error.
But I'm using WordPress so, I don't have an idea to fix it then I just leave it like this.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem

Answer (score 46):

Just add the parameter `"origin"` with the URL of your site in the `paramVars` attribute of the player, like this:

```
this.player = new window['YT'].Player('player', {
    videoId: this.mediaid,
    width: '100%',
    playerVars: { 
        'autoplay': 1,
        'controls': 0,
        'autohide': 1,
        'wmode': 'opaque',
        'origin': 'http://localhost:8100' 
    },
}
```

Comment: origin: window.location, in the properties to cover dev and production

Comment: @JamesBailey `window.location.origin` .. `window.location` is an object.

Comment: As API doc says, origin playerVar is only used with pure iframe implementation. Not JS API one.

Comment: All of these 'fixes' dont work for us here in 2020. Also to add, its random per page load when the error shows. Its a race condition between our site and youtube.

Comment: `window.location.host`

Answer (score 25):

Setting this seems to fix it:

```
  this$1.player = new YouTube.Player(this$1.elementId, {
    videoId: videoId,
    host: 'https://www.youtube.com',
```

Comment: making it `http`  (instead of `https`) solved my problem.

Comment: This fixed it for me as well. Can also do: `host: \`${window.location.protocol}//www.youtube.com\``,

Comment: All of these 'fixes' dont work for us here in 2020. Also to add, its random per page load when the error shows. Its a race condition between our site and youtube.

Comment: @IncredibleHat - Issue still exists for me in 2023. Do you have any ideas about how to solve this race condition? I suspect you are right here, because if I reduce the number of videos on my page, the error "often" goes away. It is as you say "random" on page loads.

Answer (score 12):

You can save the JavaScript into local files:

- https://www.youtube.com/player_api
- https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vfluxKqfs/www-widgetapi.js

Into the first file, `player_api` put this code:

```
if(!window.YT)var YT={loading:0,loaded:0};if(!window.YTConfig)var YTConfig={host:"https://www.youtube.com"};YT.loading||(YT.loading=1,function(){var o=[];YT.ready=function(n){YT.loaded?n():o.push(n)},window.onYTReady=function(){YT.loaded=1;for(var n=0;n<o.length;n++)try{o[n]()}catch(i){}},YT.setConfig=function(o){for(var n in o)o.hasOwnProperty(n)&&(YTConfig[n]=o[n])}}());
```

Into the second file, find the code: `this.a.contentWindow.postMessage(a,b[c]);`

and replace it with:

```
if(this._skiped){
    this.a.contentWindow.postMessage(a,b[c]); 
}
this._skiped = true;
```

Of course, you can concatenate into one file - will be more efficient.
This is not a perfect solution, but it's works!

My Source : [yt_api-concat](https://onspacer.com/files/public/inside/js/mediaplayer.yt_api.js)

Comment: Fixed it for me. Had the files locally anyway so fit my use case.

Comment: This worked for me too, but I'm not sure why.  Can you explain why this fixes it?

Comment: thank you, answered my question on second ajax call: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58232081/youtube-video-not-playing-in-second-ajaxcall

Comment: On my point of view, using local file for library, in particular for third party service library, is a very bad way to code. No ?

Comment: @DamienC It's less than ideal for sure.  But, based on all of the other "fixes" on this thread, I'm not surprised (nor do I really judge) other developers changing the API code manually.

Comment: In 2020 this also fixed it for me. I also add this line  playerVars: {'autoplay': 1,'origin': pathname}, path name being =>  let pathname = window.location.href;

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you are loading from a URL such as:

https://www.youtube.com/embed/HIbAz29L-FA?modestbranding=1&playsinline=0&showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fintercoin.org&widgetid=1

Note the "origin" component, as well as "enablejsapi=1". The origin must match what your domain is, and then it will be whitelisted and work.

Answer (score 7):

In my case this had to do with lazy loading the iframe. Removing the iframe HTML attribute `loading="lazy"` solved the problem for me.

Comment: I had a similar issue. Waiting for the iframe to be ready before starting the player solve the issue. See @KMX's answer and also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50857499/youtube-api-error-failed-to-execute-postmessage-on-domwindow

Comment: This works but it would impact page performance in case your iframe is not visible on the first fold of the page.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error. My mistake was that the `enablejsapi=1` parameter was not present in the `iframe` src.

Answer (score 4):

You also get this message when you do not specify a [targetOrigin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) in calls to `window.postMessage()`.

In this example we post a message to the first iFrame and use `*` as target, which should allow communication to any targetOrigin.

```
window.frames[0].postMessage({
                    message : "Hi there",
                    command :"hi-there-command",
                    data : "Some Data"
                }, '*')
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks it's only a Chrome security system to block repeated requests, using CORB.

https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768

In my case, YouTube was blocking Access after the first load of the same webpage which has many video API data request, high payload.

For pages with low payload, the issue does not occur.

In Safari and other non Chronuim based browsers, the issue does not occur.

If I load the webpage in a new browser, the issue does not occur, when I reload the same page, the issue appears.

Comment: Thank you for that insight about it being chrome et al. BTW I notice when I scroll down page a bit so no video embed is showing, the error count stops for good (until page reloaded). Otherwise, on fresh page load the error counter continuously keeps producing error until browser becomes unresponsive (wordpress plugin producing this brought me here).

Answer (score 2):

Try using `window.location.href` for the url to match the window's origin.

Comment: Nice, i tried all the other answers and this worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

Remove DNS Prefetch will solve this issue.

If you're using WordPress, add this line in your theme's functions.php

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_resource_hints', 2 );
```

Comment: Literalmente o código passou a funcionar, mesmo o erro ainda aparecendo no console.

Answer (score 2):

There could be any of the following, but all of them lead into DOM not loaded before its accessed by the javascript.

So here is what you have to ensure before actually calling JS code:
* Make sure the container has loaded before any javascript is called
* Make sure the target URL is loaded in whatever container it has to

I came across the similar issue but on my local when I am trying to have my Javascript run well before onLoad of the main page which causes the error message. I have fixed it by simply waiting for whole page to load and then call the required function.

You could simply do this by adding a timeout function when page has loaded and call your onload event like:

window.onload = new function() {
setTimeout(function() {
// some onload event
}, 10);
}

that will ensure what you are trying will execute well after onLoad is trigger.

Comment: Putting everything inside `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {` unfortunately didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

In my instance at least this seems to be a harmless "not ready" condition that the API retries until it succeeds.

I get anywhere from two to nine of these (on my worst-case-tester, a 2009 FossilBook with 20 tabs open via cellular hotspot).... but then the video functions properly. Once it's running my postMessage-based calls to seekTo definitely work, haven't tested others.

Comment: It sure would appear I'm wasting my time worrying about this error when in fact the web site and the embedded vids are all working fine... a user of the web site wouldn't be worrying about this, maybe I won't either.

Answer (score 2):

Extending @Hokascha's answer above it was also lazy loading for me being automatically added by WordPress. This code will remove all lazy loading on the site's iframes (add to functions.php):

```
function disable_post_content_iframe_lazy_loading( $default, $tag_name, $context ) {
    if ( 'iframe' === $tag_name ) {
        return false;
    }
    return $default;
}
add_filter('wp_lazy_loading_enabled', 'disable_post_content_iframe_lazy_loading', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

In some cases (as one commenter mentioned) this might be caused if you are moving the player within DOM, like `append` or etc..

Answer (score 1):

This helped me (with Vue.js)

Found here [vue-youtube](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-youtube)

```
mounted() {
  window.YTConfig = {
    host: 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'
  }
  const host = this.nocookie ? 'https://www.youtube-nocookie.com' : 'https://www.youtube.com'

  this.player = player(this.$el, {
    host,
    width: this.width,
    height: this.height,
    videoId: this.videoId,
    playerVars: this.playerVars
  })
  ...
}
```

**UPDATE**:
Working like a charm like this:

```
...
youtube(
  video-id="your_video_code_here"
  nocookie
)
...
data() {
  return {
    playerVars: {
      origin: window.location.href,
    },
  };
},
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What part of this code helped? (I am also facing this issue using Vue)

Answer (score 0):

I think the description of the error is misleading and has originally to do with wrong usage of the player object.

I had the same issue when switching to new Videos in a Slider.

When simply using the `player.destroy()` function [described here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Accessing_and_Modifying_DOM_Nodes) the problem is gone.

Comment: Could you please see if you understand what I'm experiencing in YouTube here and whether it's related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/57649870/470749 Maybe you'll have an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and it turns out it was because I had the Chrome extension "HTTPS Everywhere" running. Disabling the extension solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This exact error was related to a content block by Youtube when "playbacked on certain sites or applications". More specifically by WMG (Warner Music Group).

The error message did however suggest that a https iframe import to a http site was the issue, which it wasn't in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your iframe to be like this and add origin to be your current website. It resolves error on my browser.

```
<iframe class="test-testimonials-youtube-group"  type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/HiIsKeXN7qg?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://localhost:8000"
  frameborder="0">
</div>
```

ref: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player

Answer (score 0):

Just wishing to avoid the console error, I solved this using a similar approach to Artur's earlier answer, following these steps:

1. Downloaded the YouTube Iframe API (from https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api) to a local **yt-api.js** file.
2. Removed the code which inserted the www-widgetapi.js script.
3. Downloaded the www-widgetapi.js script (from https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vfl7VfO1r/www-widgetapi.js) to a local **www-widgetapi.js** file.
4. Replaced the **targetOrigin** argument in the **postMessage** call which was causing the error in the console, with a "*" (indicating no preference - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).
5. Appended the modified **www-widgetapi.js** script to the end of the **yt-api.js** script.

This is not the greatest solution (patched local script to maintain, losing control of where messages are sent) but it solved my issue.

**Please see the security warning about removing the targetOrigin URI stated here before using this solution - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage**

[Patched yt-api.js example](https://gist.github.com/stuntbaboon/abb0ce284241d51901676942d4d12a45)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `origin=${window.location.host} or "*"` is not enough.

Add `https://` before it and it will work.

Also, make sure that you are using an URL that can be embedded: take the video ID out and concatenate a string that has the YouTube video prefix and the video ID + embed definition.

Answer (score 0):

I think we could customize the sendMessage of the YT.Player

```
playerOptions.playerVars.origin = window.location.origin or your domain.
this.youtubePlayer = new YT.Player(element,playerOptions);
this.youtubePlayer.sendMessage = function (a) {
   a.id = this.id, a.channel = "widget", a = JSON.stringify(a);
   var url = new URL(this.h.src), origin = url.searchParams.get("origin");
   if (origin && this.h.contentWindow) {
       this.h.contentWindow.postMessage(a, origin)
   }
}
```

I used this function to resolve in my project.

Comment: What is `this.h.contentWindow` here. From where this comes in? Thanks!

Comment: @GRD that is the content of the function from YT.Player. you could find the function that named sendMessage on the youtube script.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error message in my attempt to embed a Stripe pricing table when:

1. Adding the embed code via PHP through a custom WordPress short code
2. Or by appending the code to the page dynamically with JavaScript (Even a using a `setTimeout()` delay to ensure the DOM was loaded didn't work).

I was able to solve this on my WordPress site by adding the code to the WordPress page itself using plain html code in the block editor.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am using Google Chrome and had the same problem for a few days. Then, I realized that the error only occurred when I used a playlist attribute to force playback in a loop. Therefore, I deleted my playlist attribute and used the onStateChange method to restart playback. If you ever encounter this problem and have a playlist attribute, it's worth checking whether it is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I use `The Angular Youtube component` here and this is what they have said about this run time error: i.e. no solution yet.

> I've seen this occasionally in our dev app as well, but I don't think
> that we can do much about it since it comes from YouTube's code that's
> isolated inside of the iframe.

Ref: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/22835#issuecomment-853176948

Answer (score -1):

mine was:

```
<youtube-player
  [videoId]="'paxSz8UblDs'"
  [playerVars]="playerVars"
  [width]="291"
  [height]="194">
</youtube-player>
```

I just removed the line with playerVars, and it worked without errors on console.

Answer (score -1):

You can try :

```
document.getElementById('your_id_iframe').contentWindow.postMessage('your_message', 'your_domain_iframe')
```

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing the same issue then I visit [official Youtube Iframe Api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) where i found this:

> The user's browser must support the HTML5 postMessage feature. Most modern browsers support postMessage

and wander to see that official page was also facing this issue. Just Visit [official Youtube Iframe Api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) and see console logs. My Chrome version is 79.0.3945.88.