# Youtube video in popcorn webmaker is not loading, Infinitely buffering a video

Tags: node.js, youtube-api, popcornjs

I am getting this error in popcorn webmaker

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.youtube.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://localhost:8888').
```

I am not able to play the you tube videos in chrome. In mozilla and safari it is working fine.

So can anybody help me out in resolving this issue.

This is the code of my iframe. I am using the latest api of youtube that is:

```
https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api
```

My Iframe code is below:-

```
<iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0Fegb4Ew8SM?butteruid=1437727498131&amp;rel=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;disablekb=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888&amp;controls=0&amp;wmode=opaque&amp;html5=1&amp;enablejsapi=1" id="widget4"></iframe>
```

The video load for 1 or 2 seconds then It goes to an infinite waiting state.

Fore more details you can visit:
54.186.240.149:8888

Please check in chrome.

Comment: Is your iFrame url using `http`? If so, you need to use `https` instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27574013/4241842

Comment: Its https not http. My iframe code is <iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0Fegb4Ew8SM?butteruid=1437727498131&amp;rel=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;disablekb=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888&amp;controls=0&amp;wmode=opaque&amp;html5=1&amp;enablejsapi=1" id="widget4"></iframe> @not_a_bot

Comment: What happens when you use `https://www.youtube.com/embed/...` instead?

Comment: Hi all, I have posted below the working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats the solution:-

```
// This function needs duration and first play to be ready.
function onFirstPlay() {
  removeYouTubeEvent( "play", onFirstPlay );
  if ( player.getCurrentTime() === 0 ) {
    setTimeout( onFirstPlay, 0 );
    return;
  }
  addYouTubeEvent( "pause", onFirstPause );
  player.pauseVideo();
  player.seekTo( 0 );
}
```

It was initially

```
// This function needs duration and first play to be ready.
function onFirstPlay() {
  removeYouTubeEvent( "play", onFirstPlay );
  if ( player.getCurrentTime() === 0 ) {
    setTimeout( onFirstPlay, 0 );
    return;
  }
  addYouTubeEvent( "pause", onFirstPause );
  player.seekTo( 0 );
  player.pauseVideo();
}
```