# postMessage error when opening URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cross-domain

I open [a link](http://www.slate.com/articles/business/the_juice/2015/07/solarcity_the_company_didn_t_invent_the_solar_panel_but_it_invented_something.html?wpsrc=sh_all_tab_tw_ru) by calling `window.open()`

I then get the following error in Google Chrome:

`Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://editorial.outbrain.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://example.com').`

What is causing this error to happen, and how can I address it?

You can recreate this error by visiting [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eqq0zkLf/) (you'll have to enable pop-ups).

Comment: Are you writing the code for slate.com or editorial.outbrain.com?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573017/failed-to-execute-postmessage-on-domwindow-https-www-youtube-com-http

Comment: @Quentin, neither, hence I'm a bit worried why their code is throwing an error on my page.