# Working locally with YouTube iframe API: "Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow"

Tags: youtube-api

I'm working on a local server, experimenting with the YouTube iframe API.

When loading iframes I get the error message  "Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow".

How do I eliminate this error?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started) in the IFRAME API page and was able to run the sample without a hitch using the `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`.

Your problem might be related to the way you're using iframe API. Check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573017/failed-to-execute-postmessage-on-domwindow-https-www-youtube-com-http) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I think we could customize the sendMessage of the YT.Player

```
playerOptions.playerVars.origin = window.location.origin or your domain.
this.youtubePlayer = new YT.Player(element,playerOptions);
this.youtubePlayer.sendMessage = function (a) {
   a.id = this.id, a.channel = "widget", a = JSON.stringify(a);
   var url = new URL(this.h.src), origin = url.searchParams.get("origin");
   if (origin && this.h.contentWindow) {
       this.h.contentWindow.postMessage(a, origin)
   }
}
```

I used this function to resolve in my project. (Origin [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70351589/2076049))