# Youtube API error - Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow':

Tags: youtube

Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow':  The target origin provided ('https://www.youtube.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://my-site.ru').

Nginx is on the sever. And of course there is a https!

But I got this error... and only in Google Chrome video didn`t start, Firefox shows all right (and Edge)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, strange error, "visibility = hidden" is a reason.
Be sure that the playback container (like its parents) is displayed before starting the player.

Comment: I was so hopeful about this, but I'm still getting `Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('<URL>') does not match the recipient window's origin ('<URL>').`

Comment: This didnt help, because our elements were not hidden, invisible, or opaqued out to begin with ;)

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue with visibility = hidden and we were able to achieve pretty much the same trick by using CSS opacity 0.