# origin youtube api Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow':

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, cross-domain

I'm getting this error when I use the Youtube API to embed a video on Chrome:

"origin youtube api Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.youtube.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('XXXXXXX')."

It works fine, but I get that error.

If I'm doing a simple Youtube iframe embed, I typically solve this problem by adding an origin setting to the URL. However, I don't seem to be able to do this with the API. I added an origin to the playerVars but it doesn't resolve the error.

```
   <script async src="https://youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
   <script>
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
      var player1;
      player1 = new YT.Player('YouTubePlayer', {
      videoId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',  
      width: 1920,                
      height: 1080,               
      playerVars: {
      autoplay: 1,         
      start: 40,
      end:640,
      controls: 0,         
      showinfo: 0,         
      enablejsapi: 1,
      origin: 'https://XXXXXXXXX.com',
      modestbranding: 1,   
      loop: 1,             
      fs: 0,               
      cc_load_policy: 0,  
      iv_load_policy: 3,   
      autohide: 0          
         },
         events: {
           onReady: function(e) {
             e.target.mute();
      player1.addEventListener('onStateChange', function(e) {

         var id = 'XXXXXXXXX';



      if(e.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED){
        player1.loadVideoById({'videoId': id,
               'startSeconds': 40,
               'endSeconds': 640,
               'suggestedQuality': 'large'});

      };
         });
           }
         }
       });
```

Where should I add an origin? Or is there another way to address this problem? Thanks!

Comment: this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47833687/youtube-api-failed-to-execute-postmessage-on-domwindow) might help.