# Slider Revolution YouTube Video not working

Tags: wordpress, youtube, youtube-api, revolution-slider

I am using Slider Revolution and I have a slide where the Main Background is a YouTube Video, the problem is the video will not play or autoplay, here are the arguments I have assigned, this does not work in Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

```
autoplay=1&mute=1&version=3&enablejsapi=1&html5=1&hd=1&wmode=opaque&showinfo=0&rel=0;
```

Sometimes I get this error:

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin
>   provided ('https://www.youtube-nocookie.com') does not match the
>   recipient window's origin ('https://mydomain.ca').

However my site is on a directory for now (https://mydomain.ca/www2) is this the reason why my video is not working? If not, then how do I fix this?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you checked if your iFrame url is using `http` or `https`? If so, have you tried visiting [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573017/failed-to-execute-postmessage-on-domwindow-https-www-youtube-com-http)?

Comment: Would you happen to know the iframe would be location in the Slider Revolution files?

Comment: for me the video works when using Firefox and fails on Chrome

Answer (score 0):

To me, it is missing the parameter `origin`:

1. Find the option of the YouTube arguments under Background -> YouTube Settings -> Arguments
2. Add `origin=https://yoursite.com;` to the end of the Arguments field.

Comment: Is this what u mean. https://imgur.com/a/X3jMQLd. but its not working