# How to fix this error? This is already live site now

Tags: wordpress

www-widgetapi.js:363 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.youtube.com') does not match the recipient window's origin.

Answer (score 0):

The issue must be a conflict between http and https. Try changing the url of the file you are trying to embed to be https. Checkout this solution [Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': https://www.youtube.com !== http://localhost:9000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573017/failed-to-execute-postmessage-on-domwindow-https-www-youtube-com-http)