# How to resolve Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow' error on angular youtube component

Tags: angular, youtube, youtube-api, angular-components

I am trying to use the new you tube component from angular. This is the first time I am using it. I referred this [article](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/the-new-angular-youtube-player-component-9ce52ecf3dee) and also the original code for the component.

In my index.html I have:

```
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

I have imported:

```
import { YouTubePlayerModule } from '@angular/youtube-player';
```

and in my component:

```
<youtube-player videoId="'exAB088mOok'" suggestedQuality="highres" [height]="300" [width]="500" [startSeconds]="43" [endSeconds]="60">
                </youtube-player>
```

Although I can see the youtube iframe loaded in my component, it doesn't work and says:

```
An error occurred. Please try again later. (Playback ID: rGdhOrRkDSd_2vzB)
Learn More
```

In my console I receive the following error:

```
www-widgetapi.js:613 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.youtube.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://localhost:4200').
```

I have tried looking up for the issue but couldn't find a solution. Most solution says its a mixed content issue between https:// and http://. However, I already have https:// script loaded in index.html

Also the target page doesn't match recipient page is ambigious. I believe target page is youtube URL and recepient page is my application URL. How are they suppose to ever match.

Perhaps I am arriving at something wrong here. Can someone explain whats going on here and provide a solution.

P.S: I have already seen this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573017/failed-to-execute-postmessage-on-domwindow-https-www-youtube-com-http), but it doesn't help me.