# Sending data from one domain to another using javascript (I have access to the <head> of both web pages)

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I have access to the `<head>` tag on both pages and I need to send data from one page to another. Both pages are on different domains.

Page A domain ([www.foo.com](http://www.foo.com))

Page B domain ([www.bar.com](http://www.bar.com))

If I declared a variable, say `var test_parameter = 'something';`... How would I get that variable from one page to the next using some sort of code in the `<head>` tag?

Comment: You either need to post to a server script that enables CORS, or you have to put the value in a URL query parameter.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) as long as one page opened the other.

---

**Page A** (https://example.org)

```
var test_parameter = 'something';

Window.open('https://example.net')
      .postMessage(test_parameter, 'https://example.net');
```

**Page B** (https://example.net)

```
window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    
    // Do not do anything unless the message was from
    // a domain we trust.
    if (event.origin !== 'https://example.org') return;

    // Create a local copy of the variable we were passed.
    var test_parameter = event.data;
    
    // Do something...

    // Optionally reply to the message (Page A must also have
    // a 'message' event listener to receive this message).
    event.source.postMessage('Done!', 'https://example.org');

}, false);
```

Comment: Doing this on a local server I keep getting:  "Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://localhost:4210') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://localhost:4200')."  So does this mean it  actually does not work cross origin?

Comment: It definitely works cross-origin. There are multiple reasons you might be getting that error; [here's a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573017/failed-to-execute-postmessage-on-domwindow-https-www-youtube-com-http) with some context and solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in [www.foo.com](http://www.foo.com)

```
var parameterValue = "something";
window.location = "www.bar.com?parameter="+parameterValue;
```

And in [www.bar.com](http://www.bar.com)

```
var parUrl = window.location.search;
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(parUrl);
var parameter = urlParams.get('parameter') // something
```