# Can I fill in an input field on another domain using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a scenario where I have no control over a web page A, which has an input field that users can fill out. On the other hand, I have a web page B under my control which runs JavaScript. Is there a way to add JavaScript to page B so that it can load page A, wait for it to finish loading, and then automatically fill in the value of the input field with a certain value?

Comment: simply add a query 
?someValue=inputValueHere
and on page B just check for this query

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66392987/sending-data-from-one-domain-to-another-using-javascript-i-have-access-to-the

duplicate of this i guess

Comment: You are not allowed to run your JavaScript on the other domain, except if they implement loading JavaScript from your server. Sometimes forms allow you to use GET request parameters, like `?name=Joe` to be in the URL.

Comment: So say web page A is the page of a bank with a bank transfer form. If this were allowed, you'd be able to just transfer money without the user knowing.

Comment: @ZhivkoNikolov OP mentions that they don't have control over web page A.

Comment: @Ivar well now I see, this is impossible.