# How to hidden parameters in url on unbounce

Tags: javascript, unbounce

I have problem in unbounce pages. I have 3 pages: landing page in domain A, TYP in domain A and finally a page for to send newsletter, but in domain B, so i have two domain for 3 pages. The question is, where the user to type name and email. He´s going to thank you page so, the name and email to stay in browser. When the user on click in the button for "go to newsletter", the name and email need to go this page, but she´s in other domain. But i need of input name and email to stay dynamic filling of input data but is´not impossible because the domains is different,

I get insert this function but only same domain
Idont need this, i have this function in different domain
Someone cant help me,
api external maybe?

Comment: Your English is difficult to understand, but am I correct that you want to send information from one domain to another? If so, you should take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/66392987/3083215

Comment: English is not my native language, I´m learning this language :D