# PostMessage from a sandboxed iFrame to the main window, origin is always null

Tags: javascript, html, postmessage

There's something I don't get about the event origin with javascript postMessage event.

Here is my main page:

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Test</h1>
<h2>Outside</h2>

<iframe src="iframe-include.html" 
    width="100%" height="100" 
    sandbox="allow-scripts"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    console.log(event);
}, false);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And my iFrame content

```
<html>
<body>

<h3>Inside</h3>

<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 1,
    domain = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host,
    send = function () {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('iframe says:', domain);
            window.parent.postMessage(counter, domain);
            counter += 1;
            send();
        }, 3000);
    };

send();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Looking at the console, the origin property of the event object is always null, even if the domain variable in the iFrame is correct.

My console says:

```
iframe-include.html:11 iframe says: http://127.0.0.1:8181
iframe.html:11 MessageEvent {isTrusted: true, data: 2, origin: "null", lastEventId: "", source: Window…}
```

In every doc, it says that it's important to check on event.origin inside de "message" event listener. But how to do that if it's always null?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided does not match the recipient window's origin ('null')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22194409/failed-to-execute-postmessage-on-domwindow-the-target-origin-provided-does)

Comment: No, it is a completely different issue, although the cause is the same. I am having it too...

Comment: @rekam How did you get that data from the console?

Comment: @kintsukuroi What do you mean exactly? I just copy-pasted the output from the Chrome console. Just tried right now and I have the same result

Comment: @rekam I mean this: iframe-include.html:11 iframe says: http://127.0.0.1:8181
iframe.html:11 MessageEvent {isTrusted: true, data: 2, origin: "null", lastEventId: "", source: Window…}, how did you get to that info?

Comment: really just copy-pasted chrome console content. The text "iframe-include.html:11 iframe says..." is not visible in the console, but when I paste it, it is here. I use Chromium 67 on Ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the iframe is sandboxed it lost access to its origin data.

adding `allow-same-origin` to the iframe sandbox property will make it work again.

Comment: Is it possible to set the origin data manually after it is lost?

Answer (score 10):

As pointed out [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/), there is a perfectly fine way to determine the sender in that scenario, without giving the `allow-same-origin` permission:

```
  // Sandboxed iframes which lack the 'allow-same-origin'
  // header have "null" rather than a valid origin. This means you still
  // have to be careful about accepting data via the messaging API you
  // create. Check that source, and validate those inputs!
  var frame = document.getElementById('sandboxed');
  if (e.origin === "null" && e.source === frame.contentWindow)
    alert('Result: ' + e.data);
```

Note that the origin isn't `null`, it's `"null"`.