# window.top.postMessage sends "null" as its event.origin

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm trying to post a message from an iframe to the parent window. I of course want to check the `origin` of the message before processing it. But it seems to be `"null"`. What am I doing wrong?

```
// Parent:
$(document).ready(function() {
  loadIframe();
  iframeListen();
});

loadIframe = function() {
  var iframe;
  iframe         = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.src     = "/load_pages.htm";
  iframe.sandbox = "allow-scripts";
  iframe.id      = "page_iframe";
  iframe.onload  = function() {
    return postToIframe();
  };
  return document.body.appendChild(iframe);
};

iframeListen = function() {
  return window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    return console.log(event.origin); // "null"
  });
};
```

The iframe sends its message like this:

```
// iframe:
<script>
  window.top.postMessage('Hello parent', '*');
</script>
```

Bonus info: When I send messages to the iframe I get the expected origin:

```
// Parent:
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.top.postMessage('Hello iframe', '*');
};

// iframe:
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  console.log(event.origin); // "http://localhost:3000"
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostMessage from a sandboxed iFrame to the main window, origin is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37838875/postmessage-from-a-sandboxed-iframe-to-the-main-window-origin-is-always-null)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? None of the other solutions on this site have resolved this for me.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?