# Why does facebook business login for instagram get stuck at connect to instagram?

Tags: javascript, facebook, dom, instagram, href

I'm trying to implement facebook business login for instagram. Below is my constructed url and the href tag calling that URL. However, the flow gets stuck at connect to instagram with the error

Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.facebook.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://web.facebook.com').
DO

```
const FACEBOOK_LOGIN_URL = `https://www.facebook.com/${FACEBOOK_API_VERSION}/dialog/oauth?client_id=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET}&display=page&extras={'setup':{'channel':'IG_API_ONBOARDING'}}&redirect_uri=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FACEBOOK_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URI}&response_type=token&scope=instagram_basic,pages_show_list,business_management,instagram_manage_messages,pages_manage_metadata,pages_messaging`;
```

```
     <a
          href={`${FACEBOOK_LOGIN_URL}`}
          className="flex flex-row items-center"
        >
          Login to Facebook
        </a>
```

I tried using "web.facebook.com" inplace of "www.facebook.com" and i still get the same issue.

Anyone run into this before and know how to fix it?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22194409/failed-to-execute-postmessage-on-domwindow-the-target-origin-provided-does) help?

Comment: @FiddlingAway this is good to know but I think this is for iframes, and initiating a post message. In my situation, I'm simply redirecting to Facebook's auth URL, and they send a post message to my window, but for some reason, there is a mismatch in target and recipient origin.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're passing `client_secret` in the url.

I think that's a bad idea because that's sensitive information that should not be publicly available. Also, the docs for [Business Login for Instagram](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/business-login-for-instagram/) does not specify a field called `client_secret`.

Just want to chime in because I'm facing the same issue. I can add that if I sign into Instagram with a "normal" profile, then it makes me convert it to a professional account. I'm still stuck at the same place as you afterwards, though.

Comment: Stumbled on this post trying to figure out how to actually get this "Business Login for Instagram" functionality to work.  When I create a link with the `extras={"setup":{"channel":"IG_API_ONBOARDING"}}` query param, I still just get the generic facebook login.  Are you seeing specific IG user onboarding steps when using the Business Login for Instagram?

Comment: Thank you @Tazz for the prompt. For me, it wasn't working without the secret so I decided to try it with the secret but I guess it's still the same, I can convert to a professional account too but I still get stuck. I also noticed it worked when I ran it on mobile, and only hangs on the PC.

Comment: @NiftyAsp Hmm that sounds strange. I get something that looks like a facebook flow, but then page clearly states that it is for Instagram and I get redirected to login on Instagram.com

Answer (score -1):

In my case in desktop it works fine because it opens a popup for the Instagram credentials, and when logged in it closes the popup and the onboarding goes to the next step automatically to select the pages and so on. But on mobile, when clicking the start button in the first step for the Instagram configuration, instead of the popup it asks me to open the Instagram app or continue the login in the browser. If I select the Instagram app then it opens but it doesnt do anything, just shows the timeline. If I select the browser, it opens a new tab and when logged in on Instagram it redirects to Facebook and keeps in a loop reloading the page

Comment: This answer does not contribute to the betterment of the thread. This is an add-on to the issue. It should not be mentioned here under the "Answers" section

Comment: This answer does not contribute to the betterment of the thread. This is an add-on to the issue. It should not be mentioned here under the "Answers" section –

Comment: Thank you @Angel, this is very helpful to know. I noticed too recently on the mobile it's behaving in a similar way for me. I'm more concerned with the desktop however, could you share how you were able to get it working? Are there any specific configurations you had to do on the meta developer platform, on Chrome, or with the construction of the URL? No matter what I do, it gets stuck right after I put in my Instagram credentials.